# How to pass 2 variables from a method to another method?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

I'm currently stuck on a problem that I can't seem to solve.

I need to pass 2 variables from this method:

```
public void neueRoute() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String bereich1 = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgG";
    String bereich2 = "hHiIjJkKlLmMnNoO";
    String start = "";
    String ziel = "";

    System.out.println("Themenbereich 1: Bahn A - G: ");
    System.out.println("\nA\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\n");
    System.out.println("Themenbereich 2: Bahn H - O: ");
    System.out.println("\nH\nI\nJ\nK\nL\nM\nN\nO");

    while (bereich1.contains(""+start) && bereich2.contains(""+ziel)
           || bereich2.contains(""+start) && bereich1.contains(""+ziel) || start.matches(ziel)) {

            System.out.println("Geben Sie einen Startpunkt an: ");
            start = in.next();

            while (!start.matches("\\b[a-oA-O]\\b")) { 
                   System.out.println("Geben Sie einen korrekten Startpunkt an: ");
                   start = in.next();
            }

            System.out.println("Geben Sie einen Zielpunkt an: ");
            ziel = in.next();

            while (!start.matches("\\b[a-oA-O]\\b")) { 
                   System.out.println("Geben Sie einen korrekten Zielpunkt an: ");
                   start = in.next();

            }   
    }


    program(start, ziel);
}
```

At the bottom I call the method program():

```
private void program(String start, String ziel) {
    // find connection from 'I' to 'O'
    connection = network.findConnection(start, ziel);

    // print the path
    System.out.println(connection.getPath());
    // print the distance
    System.out.println(connection.getTime());
}
```

And I'm trying to pass through the String variables start and ziel and use them in findConnection()

I get the error (I'm using Eclipse IDE):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: graph must contain the end vertex
```

Note: findConnection() requires String arguments, which start and ziel are. If I were to put for example "a" and "b" as arguments in findConnection() it would work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `connection` ever declared as a type?

Comment: You need to show what `findConnection()` does. It seems it can't accept empty strings presumably coming from the `neueRoute()`

Comment: Can you tell me please why the strings taht are passed are empty? I tried searching for an answer but I can't seem to find one. Because when I print start and ziel at the bottom of neueRoute(), it will print the right values.

Comment: @JoshuaDala It was just a hint. Unless you show what findConnection() does, its hard to tell why you are getting `IllegalArgumentException` from that method.

Answer (score 0):

Well probably network.findConnection is checking the values and throw an exception if empty. 
Check the Strings if blank before call the private method and if in.hasNext() (Scanner)

As for your code these are my observations:
I think your loop should be something like this, you have a mixture of ANDs and ORs

```
while ((bereich1.contains(""+start) && bereich2.contains(""+ziel)) || (bereich2.contains(""+start) && bereich1.contains(""+ziel)) || start.matches(ziel)) {
```

Secondly I think

```
System.out.println("Geben Sie einen Zielpunkt an: ");

ziel = in.next(); 
while (!start.matches("\\b[a-oA-O]\\b")) { 
System.out.println("Geben Sie einen korrekten Zielpunkt an: "); 
ziel = in.next(); //ziel not start
}
```

The thing I don't understand is you have an outer loop and inside loops should the the outer while be an if?!!!

And before call program (string, string) can you check that values are not null or empty.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer? Because if I was to print start and ziel at the bottom of my method neueRoute(), it would print the right values. But it won't be passed over to program() as arguments.

Comment: Updated my answer